# GhostScript on Iron.io Workers

Tags: ghostscript, iron.io, ironworker

Does anyone know how to get GhostScript working in Iron.io workers?

I am using the ffmpeg stack with node.js and need to convert a pdf to a series of jpegs using imagemagic and GhostScript is required for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add almost any .deb file to a worker package via keyword `deb`
(working) example:

```
runtime "node"
exec "run.js"
stack 'node-0.10'

deb 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/ghostscript/ghostscript_9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.2_amd64.deb'

remote # important, turn remote building on
```

Also, you could find some other helpful examples there: https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_examples/tree/master/deb-packages